# iOS code skipping over dispatch_async

Tags: ios, objective-c, grand-central-dispatch

I need to download data from a URL (this prints the data in JSON format) and store it in a "configuration" file for the app in the app's AppDelegate.m file. When I run the app, it simply skips over the dispatch_async code for some reason. Why is this happening and how do I fix this ?

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    //Download the config.json file
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), ^{
        NSString *configFileUrl = @"http://webserviceurl";
        //NSString *downloadToFile = @"Configuration.json";
        NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:configFileUrl]];
        [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(writeDataToConfigurationJsonFile:) withObject:data waitUntilDone:YES];
    });

 //More code below
```

And this is where I am writing the data to a file in the Documents directory of the app:

```
-(void)writeDataToConfigurationJsonFile:(NSData*)jsonData{

    NSString *content = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    //get the documents directory:
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains
    (NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

    //make a file name to write the data to using the documents directory:
    NSString *fileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/Configuration.json", documentsDirectory];

    //save content to the documents directory
    [content writeToFile:fileName
              atomically:YES
                encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding
                   error:nil];
}
```

Comment: take a look at NSURLConnection loading data asynchronously methods that should work for you

Comment: It's not skipping over it, it's returning immediately which is exactly what `dispatch_async` is supposed to do instead of blocking until finished.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the purpose of this application, the best way was to use a synchronous request rather than an asynchronous request. Here's the final chunk of code -

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"some url"]];
NSError        *error = nil;
NSURLResponse  *response = nil;
NSData *receivedData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:receivedData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"response");

NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains
(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

//make a file name to write the data to using the documents directory:
NSString *fileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/Configuration.json", documentsDirectory];
//save content to the documents directory

[string writeToFile:fileName
         atomically:YES
           encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding
              error:nil];
```

Answer (score 1):

`performSelectorOnMainThread` is a run loop method, you need to use:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{/*code*/});
```

Comment: same issue. it is still skipping over it

Comment: what do you mean by skipping, exactly?

Comment: I have set 2 breakpoints - The first at the line: NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL ... and the second just after the block. It does not even hit the first breakpoint

Comment: And I notice that the file Configuration.json is not created

Comment: Thought I would mention, using breakpoints like that with blocks can confuse matters. Blocks perform work asynchronously but return immediately. So if you break on the breakpoint right after your block, that does not necessarily mean that your block got 'skipped', just maybe that is not yet executing (because it's async). If you place a breakpoint in JUST the block, does it get there?

Comment: No. Also, it does not create the "Configuration.json" file in the Documents directory of the app

Answer (score 1):

You can nest a call to dispatch_sync() within dispatch_async() to ensure after the data is downloaded, the data is written synchronously on the main thread.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    //Download the config.json file
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), ^{
        NSString *configFileUrl = @"http://webserviceurl";
        //NSString *downloadToFile = @"Configuration.json";
        NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:configFileUrl]];

        dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [self writeDataToConfigurationJsonFile:data];
        });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you're asynchronously dispatching a thread, create a new serial/concurrent queue.

And for the synchronous dispatch, go back to the main queue (try without using 'waitUntilDone:YES'):

```
    dispatch_async(dispatch_queue_create("com.yourOrgName", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL), ^{

    NSString *configFileUrl = @"http://webserviceurl";
    //NSString *downloadToFile = @"Configuration.json";
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:configFileUrl]];
    dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^ {
    [self performSelector:@selector(writeDataToConfigurationJsonFile:)     withObject:data afterDelay:0.0f];

      });
     });
```